# Sql server table can be queried but not updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have a table which was always updatable before, but then suddenly i can no longer update the any of the columns in the table.  i can still query the whole table and the results come back very fast, but the moment i try to update a column in the table, the update query simply stalls and does nothing.

i tried using

```
select req_transactionUOW
from master..syslockinfo
where req_spid = -2
```

to see if some orphaned transaction was locking the table, but it returns no results.

i can't seems to find signs of my table being locked, but simply cannot update it.  any clues as to how to fix the table or whatever state it is in?

Comment: What happens when you try to update it?  Does the query timeout, or does it return an error?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please issue this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
```

which will skip the locked records and make sure it returns the same number of records as

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
```

You may need to repeat it with every index on the table forced, to make sure that no index resources is locked as well.

Comment: i tried it the queries you provided and then tried each one with the indexes individually and they all returned the same number of rows

Comment: @Nigel: does the `UPDATE` lock on any record or one some specific records only? Does it lock when you try to update other columns?

Comment: i an unable to update any row on any column.  the update query just seems to want to run forever when it should only take a split second

Answer (score 1):

When you say "times out", does it hit the client timeout? For example, the default .net command timeout is 30 seconds. I would suggest increasing this to a very large value or running the update in SQL tools (by default no timeout set).

Other than that, an update *will* finish at some point or error and rollback: are you leaving enough time?

There is also the blocking, last index rebuild, last statistics update, triggers, accidental cross join, MDF or LDF file growth, poor IO, OS paging... etc. And have you restarted the SQL instance or server to remove environmental issues and kill *all* other connections?

There simply isn't enough information to make a judgement right now sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update other tables? If not (or anyways, if you like) you could check if the transaction log is full (if you use the full recovery model)/the partition your transaction log resides on is full. I think if SQL Server is unable to write to the transaction log you would/could experience this behaviour.

DBCC would be your friend: `DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)` shows you, how much (in percent) of your log is used. If it is (close to) 100% this might be your issue.

Just my two pennies worth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this isn't a permissions issue as you're not getting an error.

So the closest I have had to this before is when the indexes on the table have become corrupt. Have you tried dropping the indexes and recreating them? Try one by one at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect locking, one of the first things I would do would be to run `sp_lock`.  It will give you a list of all of the current locks held.  You can use the `DB_NAME` and `OBJECT_NAME` functions to get the names that correspond to the `dbid` and `ObjId` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any triggers on the table? 
If so it could be that the trigger is failing so preventing the update.